# Why is my bash input getting mixed with my program output before hitting enter?

Tags: java, multithreading, bash

I've been trying to make a monitor java program that prints out some stats from concurrent threads while taking user input at the same time. And the problem i'm facing is that if a user was writing a long command "create file /home/user/etc" for example and a concurrent thread happened to print out some messages in the middle of his command. his command would be cut in half which i know won't effect the actual input i get but it ruins the user interface.

[A terminal picture to illustrate the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVuwm.png) 
in this picture i was atempting to write "why does this keep being interrupted????" and you can see what happens.

so how can i separate the command line from the output so it doesn't get interrupted while keeping both on the same window?

I am using bash on Putty if that's relevant.
I appreciate all help.

Comment: As i understand you run some program that run concurrent thread and after that run your monitoring program. For solving problem you can just run your monitoring program in another tab of console.

Comment: That does not actually solve the problem. my problem is i want the program to get user input and display any background messages at the same time. i know this can be done because I've seen java programs do it. thanks for trying to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can discern, what you're trying to do isn't possible. You have a few different options that I can think of:

1) Use a [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) java library (such as [jcurses](https://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/)).

2) Only write out data to a file.

3) Create a java GUI with separate input and output text fields/areas.

Comment: I think its possible because I have seen it in other java programs. like a spigot minecraft server for example where the command you are writing does not get mixed with the console output

Comment: @xunatai is correct, this is the standard way terminals work. Hence the suggestion for ncurses, a library for manipulating terminal data in arbitrary ways. You might be able to turn on a raw mode ( not sure if any readline library will help ), then keep track of the characters the user is writing. Have output erase the current line, write the output, then rewrite what the user was in the middle of doing ( accounting for characters input during output etc ).

Comment: @MichaelSpeer what you said made perfect sense. its something that i tried to do but i can't find any way to erase a current line or to even keep track of the characters being inputted before the user hits enter. I've read all the documentation on output streams and input streams but the terminal seems to have a built in buffer somehow that prevents any input from being sent till the "\n" character is sent.

Comment: This is why I mentioned "raw mode". It's a special mode you can put some terminals into that keeps input from being buffered, passing each keystroke to the underlying program. You're heading down a rabbit-hole of fractal complexity. Your minecraft thing probably doesn't print asynchronous data, making input and output easier. If you're writing an interface, consider having your debugging from asynchronous threads written to a file, like @xunatai also mentioned. Then only accept instructions, respond immediately, and loop.